# sql to_char - format based on date condition

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-char

This is for a monthly report that looks at last twelve months e.g. produced Jan. 2018 to look at Dec.2016 - Dec.2017.

I need to produce a case/when that formats a date based on condition -- if {prod_date} is last available month in dataset, then format as week-end date (12/2/2017,12/9/2017,12/16/2017, etc. - yyyyddmm). If, however, date is earlier than previous month, then format as 'yyyymm'.

End result groups should be:

```
20170212
20170912
20171612
20172312
20173012
201711
201710
201709
...
201612
```

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself, please clarify. In one place you say "produced Jan. 2018 so look at Dec. 2016 - Dec. 2017" (which, as any six-year-old kid who can count knows, is thirteen months, not twelve - so please clarify that too). In another place you say "last available month **in the dataset**. If the last date for 2017 IN THE DATASET is from October 2017, then that is the last month IN THE DATASET, not December 2017. So - please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understand your request:

1. You want to group by yyyymm for all months except for the last one.
2. You want to group by yyyyddmm for the last month, where dd shall be the week end (a Saturday).

Use a `CASE` expression to check the month. Truncate to ISO week to get a week's Monday. Add five days to get the Saturday. Group by the computed date string and aggregate whatever values you want. E.g.:

```
select
  grp,
  max(value1) as max_value1,
  sum(value2) as sum_value2
from
(
  select
    case when to_char(dt, 'yyyymm') = (select to_char(max(dt), 'yyyymm') from mytable)
      then to_char(trunc(dt, 'iw') + 5, 'yyyyddmm')
      else to_char(dt, 'yyyymm')
    end as grp,
    value1,
    value2
  from mytable
)
group by grp
order by grp desc;
```

Comment: I am not sure how you can interpret "the week-end date" to mean "the start of a week (a Monday)" - but the OP also gave explicit examples of dates in December 2017, all of which are Saturdays. So it is more likely that week means "from Sunday to Saturday" (as is common in the U.S. for example), and "week-end date" actually means what it says.

Comment: @mathguy: Thank you. You are right of course. Luckily it's rather easy to get from a Monday to the Saturday; I only had to add 5 days :-)